# web3 getAccounts doesn't get resolved

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

web3.eth.getAccounts() is not working for me. The code below shows "error" on execution (gets rejected). I am using web3 1.0.0 beta-46. I am learning from Stephen Grider's tutorial videos and he used beta-26, is it version related issue or am i doing something wrong?

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

web3.eth.getAccounts()
    .then(fetchedAccounts => {
      console.log(fetchedAccounts);
    },() => {
      console.log("error");
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but this seems to be a bug with the latest versions of web3. Try with 1.0.0 beta-37.

Comment: Omg! it works XD... I just installed beta-37 and it showed me the list ^_^ But should i accept your answer and close this question or let it stay since it still is an issue with beta-46 ! what do u say ? I

Comment: I'd rather open an issue on `web3.js` if it isn't done already and resolve this, but  by all mean wait a day or two to see if someone has a workaround for latest versions before marking the question as solved ! :)